# How to use a service from a separate Ionic 4 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Failed to inject/load a service from a separate Ionic 4 application to our main Ionic 4 application.

The purpose is using the services in the SHARED application in our MAIN (customer) application and a SECONDARY (owner) application. But it results in a StaticInjectionError:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BusinessService -> HttpClient]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BusinessService -> HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BusinessService -> HttpClient]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BusinessService -> HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (core.js:717)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:954)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
>       at

---

**Set-up**

- MAIN APP

**Orders.page.ts** (with BusinessService imported from SHARED)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BusinessService } from '../../../../Shared/src/app/providers/business.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders',
  templateUrl: './orders.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orders.page.scss']
})

export class OrdersPage implements OnInit {

  businessList: any;

  constructor(
    private businessService: BusinessService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showBusinesses();
  }

  showBusinesses() {
    this.businessService.getBusinesses().subscribe(data => { 
    this.businessList = data; });
  }

}
```

**App.module.ts** (with BusinessService imported from SHARED)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BusinessService } from '../../../Shared/src/app/providers/business.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    BusinessService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

---

**Set-up**

- SHARED APP

**business.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BusinessService {

  baseURL: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.baseURL = 'http://192.168.10.107:3000/api';
  }

  getBusinesses() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/businesses');
  }

}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

---

**Our thoughts**

Correct us if we are wrong!

The error is produced from the `private http: HttpClient` in app.module.ts. If we delete this, the error is gone.

So we tried to place the service inside the MAIN application with the exact same code and this works perfectly. So we think the problem is the import/connection between the two apps.

We did this successfully in Ionic 3, so are we missing anything in the new Ionic 4?

**EDIT 1:** placed app.module.ts from SHARED app

Comment: Does your shared-app has a module file associated with it? If yes, then you should be importing `HttpClientModule` over there.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Yes, I have added the app.module.ts file from Shared.

Comment: Plus the business.service.ts is a generated service file